# How to order user messages for display based on send date?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have an app where I store user message data in a SQLite database. I want to be able to access the most recent text from each message thread. Currently I have a method which pulls info from the local DB as follows:

```
var messagesPulled: [pulledMessage]!

        if openDatabase(){
            let query = "select * from messages order by messageNumber asc"
            do{
                print(database)
                let results: FMResultSet = try database.executeQuery(query, values: nil)

                while results.next(){

                    let message = pulledMessage(convoWithUserID: String(describing: results.string(forColumn: "convoWithUserID")), convoWithUserName: String(describing: results.string(forColumn: "convoWithUserName")), messageString: String(describing: results.string(forColumn: "messageString")), senderID: String(describing: results.string(forColumn: "senderID")), timeSent: String(describing: results.string(forColumn: "timeSent")), messageNumber: Int(results.int(forColumn: "messageNumber")))
                    if messagesPulled == nil{
                        messagesPulled = [pulledMessage]()
                    }
                    messagesPulled.append(message)
                    print("The message that we have pulled are \(message)")
                }

            }
            catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            database.close()
        }
        return messagesPulled
```

The issue is that I want each message thread (based on `convoWithUserID`) to be its own individual object in the array to populate tables (think regular messaging between users on the iOS message app). This is not *too* hard and can be accomplished via:

```
func pullSQLData(messageSet: [message]) -> [String:[message]]{
    var i = 0
    var messageUserID = String()
    while i < messageSet.count{
        if (messageSet[i]).userID != messageUserID{
            print("It wasn't equal")
            print(messageSet[i])
            messageUserID = messageSet[i].userID
            if messageConvoDictionary[messageUserID] != nil{
                messageConvoDictionary[messageUserID]?.append(messageSet[i])
            }else{
                messageConvoDictionary[messageUserID] = []
                messageConvoDictionary[messageUserID]?.append(messageSet[i])
            }
            i = i + 1
        }else{
            messageConvoDictionary[messageUserID]?.append(messageSet[i])
            i = i + 1
        }
    }
    print(messageConvoDictionary)
    print(i)
    return messageConvoDictionary

}
```

The issue is that I want to populate a general message table (think the way iOS deals with your own text messaging) where the general table is populated with the most recent text for each message conversation. The problem is that I do not know how to do this. I can group the messages based on what conversation they in the same way as above (assuming a simplified struct)

This function groups all of the message strings together based on what conversation they are from. What I would like to do is efficiently get the most recent message from each conversation to populate the general text table (in much the same way your phone does). I would like to do this via the `createdAt`, a property which will be a part of every object (though not expressly expressed here) that reflects the creation date of the creation of the object. My question is how do I gather the most recent message from each conversation to display on the general messaging screen (which just displays the most recent message from each convo)?

Here is an example of what would be in the SQL db and what I would want out of it:

```
convoWithUserID  convoWithUserName  messageString  sender      timeSent      messageNumber

abc123           kevin              yo man         xyz987      2017-11-01 4:23:07.000  1            
abc123           kevin              hey dude, wha  abc123      2017-11-01 4:25:13.000  2            
fgh456           jason              you going?     xyz987      2017-11-01 4:28:09.000  3            
abc123           kevin              nothing        xyz987      2017-11-01 4:39:47.000  4            
fgh456           jason              no             fgh456      2017-11-01 4:52:13.000  5
```

(xyz987 would be the current user's userID for this example). I would like to have each cell in the general "see all messages" table (like opening the message app on iPhone and seeing all of the conversations) display the most recent message from each conversation. In this case I would see two cells, one with the message just sent from jason saying "no" with a time stamp of 4:52 and the second with the message just to kevin saying "nothing" with a time stamp of 4:39. The most recent messages obviously wont be the very last ends of the table every single time.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: @CL. please see the amended question which includes the example SQL database and another explanation of what I would want from it.

Comment: This is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Comment: @CL. I have updated the strings to an appropriate format. They were just made up by me on the spot before and were wrong because of that. In the app they will be autocreated in the correct format by the `Date()` function, so they will be correct. How do I organize my data as per the question, though?

Comment: The milliseconds are optional (see the [exact definition of time strings](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)), but the hours format is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To get one output row for each group of table rows, use GROUP BY. To select from which row data is returned, use MAX() (this requires SQLite 3.7.11 or later):

```
SELECT ...,
       MAX(timeSent)
FROM messages
GROUP BY convoWithUserID
ORDER BY ...;
```